# THREE.js THREE.TransformControls is not a constructor

Tags: html, import, three.js

I am a green hand.These days,I try to learn how to use THREE.js to import .pcd files.But when i try to import {TransformControls},there is a problem that needs to be solved —— my TransformControls import failed.I try to figure out what the problem is.Here is my scripts and problem.

scripts:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>原神,启动!</title>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "../js/three.module.js",
                "three/adds/": "../js/"
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        //导入库
        import * as THREE from 'three';
        import { PCDLoader } from 'three/adds/PCDLoader.js';
        import { DragControls } from 'three/adds/DragControls.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from "three/adds/OrbitControls.js"
        import { TransformControls } from "three/adds/TransformControls.js";

        // 获取HTML页面中的容器元素
        const container = document.getElementById('container');
        // 获取HTML页面中的容器元素
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        // 创建相机
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        const helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( camera ); 
        scene.add( helper );    
        // 创建render
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true, // 开启抗锯齿
        });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        // 添加使用镜头转换控制器
        const orbitControls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        orbitControls.enableDamping = true;//阻尼效果开启
        orbitControls.update()
        // 创建一个空物体作为Points点云的父物体
        var parent1 = new THREE.Object3D();
        var parent2 = new THREE.Object3D();
        // 创建一个PCDLoader对象
        const loader = new PCDLoader();     
        loader.load('../image/cat.pcd', function (points) {
            parent1.add(points);
            scene.add(parent1);
            points.material.color.set(0x0000ff);
            camera.lookAt(parent1.position);
        });
        loader.load('../image/keqing.pcd', function (points) {
            parent2.add(points);
            scene.add(parent2);
            points.material.color.set(0x9400D3);
        });
        //修改摄像机位置
        camera.position.x = 300;
        camera.position.z = 0;
        camera.position.y = 0;      
        //修改世界坐标系位置
        scene.rotation.x = 11;
        scene.position.y = -150;
        scene.position.z = -50;
        //修改keqing位置与cat保持一致
        parent2.scale.x = 180;
        parent2.scale.y = 180;
        parent2.scale.z = 180;
        parent2.position.y = 0;
        parent1.position.y = -100;
        parent1.position.z = 50;

        // 创建一个TransformControls控制器
        var transformControls1 = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        var transformControls2 = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        transformControls1.setMode ('rotate');
        transformControls1.setSpace ('local');
        transformControls2.setMode ('rotate');
        transformControls2.setSpace ('local');
        // 将变换控件附加到目标对象上并添加到场景中
        transformControls1.attach(parent1);
        transformControls2.attach(parent2);
        scene.add (transformControls1);
        scene.add (transformControls2);

        //创建一个DragControls对象，并传入数组、相机和渲染器的DOM元素
        var objects = [parent1, parent2];
        var dragControls = new DragControls(objects, camera, renderer.domElement);
        
        // 为DragControls对象添加事件监听函数
        dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
             //当拖拽开始时，取消动画循环
            cancelAnimationFrame(animateId);
        });

        dragControls.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
            // 当拖拽进行时，更新相机的目标点为被拖拽物体的中心
            
        });

        dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
            // 当拖拽结束时，恢复动画循环
            //animate();
        });
        var animateId;

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            orbitControls.update()
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
            parent1.rotation.z += 0.001;
            parent2.rotation.z += 0.001;
        }       
        animate();
        /*
        // 以下是我添加的代码，用于实现controls窗口

        // 引入dat.gui.js库，用于创建controls窗口
        import * as dat from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.7/dat.gui.module.js';

        // 创建一个dat.GUI对象，并设置其宽度和位置
        var gui = new dat.GUI({width: 300}); // 设置controls窗口的宽度为300像素
        gui.domElement.id = 'gui'; // 设置controls窗口的id为'gui'

        // 为dat.GUI对象添加一些控件，用于显示和修改场景中的一些参数
        gui.add(scene.rotation, 'x', 0, Math.PI * 2).name('场景旋转X'); // 添加一个控件，用于调整场景的X轴旋转角度
        gui.add(scene.position, 'y', -200, 200).name('场景位置Y'); // 添加一个控件，用于调整场景的Y轴位置
        gui.add(parent1.position, 'z', -100, 100).name('猫位置Z'); // 添加一个控件，用于调整猫的Z轴位置
        gui.add(parent2.position, 'z', -100, 100).name('刻晴位置Z'); // 添加一个控件，用于调整刻晴的Z轴位置
*/
    </script>
    <style>
        /* 以下为添加的样式规则，用于调整controls窗口的位置和外观 */
        /* #gui {
          /* position: absolute; /* 设置controls窗口的定位方式为绝对定位 */
          /* top: 0; /* 设置controls窗口的上边距为0 */
          /* right: 0; /* 设置controls窗口的右边距为0 */
          /* z-index: 10; /* 设置controls窗口的层叠顺序为10，使其位于其他元素之上 */
        /* }*/ 
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
<html>
```

problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLevp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GufER.png)

And my root directory is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnd9i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNR5g.png)

If any experts know how to solve it, please help me solve it. Thank you very much!o(╥﹏╥)o

Try:import TransformControls into project
Expect to happen: import successfully
resulted: import failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a module like so:

```js
import { TransformControls } from "three/adds/TransformControls.js";
```

Then you need no `THREE` namespace when creating an instance. So instead of:

```js
var transformControls1 = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

do this:

```js
var transformControls1 = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```